# Rewriting URL with authorization

Tags: asp.net-core, authentication, reverse-proxy, grafana, asp.net-core-middleware

I'm trying to implement an AuthProxy using asp.net core.

I have a web app that requires login (to Serve A). The client gets the token in order to use the server API. In addition I have another server (Server B - Grafana in my case) that requires also authentication but can be override when it gets a specific header on its file requests.

In my app, after login, the user is pressing on some tab and seeing an `iframe` of my server B UI.
I've attached a `authKey` parameter equals the user Token for verifying it in the server (Server A). For ex.
`localhost:1234/proxy?authKey=1234`

In server A, I've develop a `ReverseProxyMiddleware` ([as explained here](https://auth0.com/blog/building-a-reverse-proxy-in-dot-net-core/)) that catches `request.Path` who starts with `/proxy` and rewriting it to server B (Grafana) with an additional header value accordingly to the `authKey` we received earlier (An algorithm is being applied on this `authKey`).

This new uri (Grafana server) is embedding and calling dynamicily to allot of urls that have to have this header I've added earlier to the main url.. How can I know if i should or not add the header if i don't get the auth anymore..

Each invoke method in my middleware run separately from each other and I do not know that they are all coming from the same session.

Any ideas how can i achieve what i want ?

Comment: Can you carry cookies when rewriting?

Comment: I just went to sleep yesterday and thought about this idea as well.. I'm not from the server world - more a client side developer.. Anyway! tried it now. and Boom! Works like a charm !

Answer (score 0):

The problem was Grafana - Without parenthesis this time (v. 7.3.2). After sending them the right header to the login page they should have return a session cookie in order to function properly - But they don't.

So, in my proxy I've created my session cookie with my data and processing it like i want and sending them over and over the wanted header.